# Can't get rid of a loop when certain conditions are met

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I've created a script in python to get the first 400 links of search results from bing. It's not sure that there will always be at least 400 results. In this case the number of results is around 300. There are 10 results in it's landing page. However, the rest of the results can be found traversing next pages. The problem is when there is no more next page link in there, the webpage displays the last results over and over again.

Search keyword is `michael jackson` and ths is a full-fledged ***[link](https://www.bing.com/search?q=michael+jackson&first=1)***

> How can I get rid of the loop when there are no more new results or the results are less than 400?`

I've tried with:

```
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = "https://www.bing.com/search?"

params = {'q': 'michael jackson','first': ''}

def get_bing_results(url):
    q = 1
    while q<=400:
        params['first'] = q
        res = requests.get(url,params=params,headers={
            "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.97 Safari/537.36"
            })
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
        for link in soup.select("#b_results h2 > a"):
            print(link.get("href"))

        time.sleep(2)
        q+=10

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_bing_results(link)
```

Comment: Can you keep track of the page number? And if the page number in the current loop is the same as the page number in the last loop then break?

Comment: Sorry, the next page number seems to generate dynamically which I can't track using requests.

Comment: BeautifulSoup should be able to pull the page number out though. Or is should be in the URL bar right? (I haven't done this before).

Comment: @MITHU, elaborate 2 moments: "new results" and "webpage displays the last results over and over again" - how do you distinguish those "new"?

Comment: You could hold the previous soup object and compare it to the new one, if they match you can break out of the loo, if they're different, carry on?

Comment: At some point of looping when that site are done displaying results, there will not be new results (only repeating the earlier results) even If the loop goes on @ RomanPerekhrest.

Comment: @MITHU have you tried my answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I mentioned in the comments, couldn't you do something like this:

```
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

link = "https://www.bing.com/search?"

params = {'q': 'michael jackson','first': ''}

def get_bing_results(url):
    q = 1
    prev_soup = str()
    while q <= 400:
        params['first'] = q
        res = requests.get(url,params=params,headers={
            "User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/78.0.3904.97 Safari/537.36"
            })
        soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
        if str(soup) != prev_soup:
            for link in soup.select("#b_results h2 > a"):
                print(link.get("href"))
            prev_soup = str(soup)
        else:
            break
        time.sleep(2)
        q+=10

if __name__ == '__main__':
    get_bing_results(link)
```

Comment: Yep, I'm trying with your answer. This is the very logic that I was trying to apply but couldn't find any idea to do that myself until I see yours. However, I'll let you know where I'm upto.

Comment: I just ran it and it seems to do the job for me, let me know if it works for you.